# Any Installation Pointers for Newbie?

Tags: command-line, system-installation

I've decided to go ahead and make the change to Ubuntu; and based strictly on a first-ever positive experience with the USB Ubuntu Desktop Trial.  All seems okay, finally, as far as hardware and drivers (Dell Intel board) under the default install.  Presently running Win7pro; and I haven't got a clue: Will the installer do everything for me, or do I need to learn a bit of the command prompt coding that I keep seeing here on the forum?  I recall learning all Dos5 (cmd prompt) within a few hours, but how deep is Ubuntu Desktop?  Any pointers or links would be appreciated; and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a Ubuntu newbie myself I can only share my experience thus far. The Ubuntu Software Center helps for managing software without working with the command prompt. While I'm not qualified to make this statement, avoiding the terminal altogether isn't an option. As I've learned more commands and shortcuts, my speed of interaction has increased.

The Ubuntu Desktop has a lot of depth to it, so it really depends on what you want to do. For example, if you mostly surf the web and use simple programs like word processing and playing music, you can avoid using the terminal.

The Installer will get you set up with most of the basics, past that you can find a lot of other programs in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

If you install from Live CD/USB it should do everything for you (unless there is a problem, which is rare if the hardware is fine in the Live USB version). You can even carry on trying Ubuntu while you install it (I often play FreeCell while the install is going).